# .mdf to .csv conversion using asammdf

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, mdf, asammdf

I am using asammdf lib to convert .mdf to df object. But in df i got some random float values in place of some string like "NOVALUE". How to avoid randomly filling items while converting mdf_to df?

eg:
I had crosschecked with Original CSV:
0             NOVALUE   NOVALUE           NOVALUE             NOVALUE
0.10000087    NOVALUE   0             NOVALUE             NOVALUE
0.20000173  82.890625   0             NOVALUE             NOVALUE

mdf to csv using asammdf output df:
0.000000             983.984375               65535           327.67     511.984375
0.100001             983.984375                   0           327.67     511.984375
0.200002              82.890625                   0           327.67     511.984375

Comment: what is your code ? can you share how you write mdf to csv ?

Comment: `from asammdf import MDF`
`mdf_obj = MDF('****.mdf')`
`df = mdf_obj.to_dataframe(time_as_date=True)`
`print(df.head())`